# CreateFragment called twice when called viewPager.setCurrentItem by button

Tags: android

When use viewPager2.setCurrentItem(viewPager2.getCurrentItem()+1,true); for changing current item by a button, createFragment in FragmentStateAdapter class runs twice (currentItem+1 and currentItem + 2)

Answer (score 3):

This is normal.

`ViewPager` will load two fragments. One that will be displayed and the fragment next to the new fragment. This way, it can properly display both fragments when scrolling to the next page.

Comment: But when i scroll it by touch does not happen run twice

Comment: Because when you scroll, the next item (which was already loaded) is displayed. Then, it just need to load the item next to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I use viewpager2 for a wizard in my app and one off fragment send data to server and next receive other data base on it from server. when i use setcurrentItem for change page second fragment calling while previous fragment not yet sent data to server. In touch createFragment do not run twice and work correctly.

Comment: But if there is options enabled ,it will duplicate. That is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid twice call createFragment() on move to next page on button click. Set smoothScroll to false. Without using setOffscreenPageLimit() in FragmentStateAdapter().

```
binding.btnNext.setOnClickListener {
                binding.viewPager.setCurrentItem(binding.viewPager.currentItem + 1, false)
      }
```

Adapter:

```
class DemoCollectionAdapter(
    fragment: ControllerQuestionPaperFragment,
    var language: ArrayList<QuestionData>
) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = language.size

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return language.get(position).qid!!.toLong()
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        val fragment = QuestionFragment()
        fragment.arguments = Bundle().apply {
            // The object is just an integer.
            putInt("position", position)
        }
        return fragment
    }
}
```